# Difference between multi-container pod vs multiple pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

What are the main differences between running multiple deployments (X,Y,Z) interconnecting using services and a single deployment/pod with multiple containers (X,Y,Z) running inside it? Specifically in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

**Multi-container POD :**

You are running multiple containers inside a single POD. All can connect each other over the Localhost. All POD running multiple containers.

**Multiple Pods:**

Different containers running on different PODs. Each POD containing one or more container and running it.

Performance-wise there might be a minor difference but still without testing actual scenario can't confirm.

Multiple containers running in a single POD so they talk to each other on localhost.

While multiple PODs interconnecting to each other over Kubernetes Service or POD to POD communication in that case minor delays may occur.